# Code is not executing until after promise completed its job

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise

This question I have might not have anything to do with angular concept. But I am encountering it in the context of angular. I click on a button in angular template, and it triggers onSubmit function.

scanFiles is a long-running function that returns a promise. I expect console.log("test1") to print out right before the long running function kick in. But that not happen. It only print out after the long running function completed.  Why is that so?

```
    onSubmit(){

        this.scanFiles(this.foldersPath).then((filesPath)=>{
                 //after scan finish 

        })
         .catch((err)=>console.log(err))

        console.log("test1")

    }
```

Further updates on 7 Oct 2019)

As can be seen below, my scanFiles function return a promise. Hence no matter what my promise job does, theoretically, I thought 'test1" should be printed out, before the browser start executing the promise job.

```
scanFiles(foldersPath: any):Promise<string[]> {
        return new Promise(
            (resolveFn, rejectFn)=>{
                try{

                    const scanResult:string[]= foldersPath.reduce(
                        (prevFolderPath:string[], currFolderPath:string)=> {
                            let files:string[] =  this.fileService.getContentInDirectory (currFolderPath, this.filter.bind(this), this.getProcessDirectoryContentFn(), this.subfolderDepthInput)
                            prevFolderPath.push(...files)
                            return prevFolderPath

                        },new Array<string>())
                    console.log(scanResult)
                    resolveFn(scanResult)
                }
                catch(e){
                    console.log(e)
                    rejectFn(e)
                }
            }
        )
``
```

Updated on 8 Oct 2019
There is a readdirSync() function inside geContentInDirectory

```
getContentInDirectory(dir:string, filterContentFn?:(fullPath:string)=>boolean, processContentFn?:(fullPath:any)=>string, maxSubFolderDepth?:number ): string[]{

        let paths:string[]=[];

        //const dir_NOT_A_DIRECTORY = 
        if(!dir || !fs.lstatSync(dir).isDirectory()) 
            throw new Error("First Parameter must be a directory")

        fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(entityName=>{
            let fullPath:string = path.join(dir, entityName)
            let isFile = fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isFile()

            if(maxSubFolderDepth==undefined || maxSubFolderDepth >= 0){
                if(isFile){
                    if(filterContentFn) {
                        if(filterContentFn(fullPath)){
                            let content = processContentFn? processContentFn(fullPath): fullPath
                            paths.push(content)
                        }            
                    }
                }
                else {
                    const depth = maxSubFolderDepth==undefined ? undefined: maxSubFolderDepth-1
                    paths.push(...this.getContentInDirectory(fullPath, filterContentFn, processContentFn, depth))
                }
            }
        })
        return paths;

    }
}
```

Updated on 8 Oct 2019

I done an experiment by rewriting my code like this:
The result is "test0", "test2", "test1" is printed out in this sequence.

**Conclusion**: When promise object is being created, its long running job defined inside the promise object will get fired and executed immediately. 
Once my scanFiles completed its job, "test0" is printed.

The callback is then registered (registered, but not yet executed) in the promise's then function. Then test2" is printed. The thread will then go back to its event loop, and discover it still need to handle the callback function, resulting in the "test1" being printed

```
let p= this.scanFiles(this.foldersPath)
console.log("test0")
p.then((filesPath)=>{
  console.log("test1")
 })
 .catch((err)=>console.log(err))

 console.log("test2")
```

Thanks to **Tomalak** user for his solution and explanation, which lead to my above understanding.

**ANSWER** to my question: My Promise object contains synchronous tasks inside. No wonder my "test1" (refer to my topmost code) is printed out only after the tasks in the promise object has completed.

Comment: In the shown snippet, the order of execution is this: 1) `this.scanFiles()` is called, 2) `.then()` callback is registered, 3) `.catch()` callback is registered, 4) `console.log()` is called. If `scanFiles` really does not block, then `console.log()` is called before the `scanFiles` result is handled. If that's not the case, then `scanFiles` does not do what you claim.

Comment: In other words, without seeing the body of `scanFiles` it's not possible to say what's going on.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replies. I have added the body of scanFiles

Comment: To add-on, I replace the scanFiles with another dummy function, which returns a promise and the promise does only 1 task: -  setTimeout for 10seconds. To my suprise, the "task1" was printed out immediately, before the promise job kicks in. Then why does that not happen to my scanFile function?

Comment: Functions do not magically *become* asynchronous just because you wrap them in `new Promise()`. From what I see in the code, what you have is a synchronous function that returns a promise. Using a promise here is completely superfluous & the behavior you see is exactly the behavior I would expect.

Comment: ...and in order to say why `scanFiles()` is not asynchronous, we would have to take a look at `getContentInDirectory()` (possibly the other functions, too).

Comment: added the getContentInDirectory().   
My god, i really thought just by returning a new Promise(), the thread will continue to execute to print out the "test1", after which it will then execute the job in the promise.

Comment: Nope. JavaScript is single-threaded. `new Promise()` does not create a new thread.

Comment: ...and there is the problem. `getContentInDirectory` uses `fs.readdirSync` and `fs.lstatSync`, wich means it will be blocking code. Rewrite it so that it uses `fs.readdir` and `fs.lstat` and returns a promise. You can then keep returning that promise all the way to the result of `scanFiles`. If you're on node 10.0.0+, you can use `fsPromises` instead of `fs` to make your life easier.

Comment: Hi, noted. I will try that out, and let u know. I am aware that the Javascript is single thread. I thought the thread will create a new Promise(), and return it back to the caller, and then proceed to print out the "test". Then when the thread is back to its event loop, it detect it need to run the long running job, then it start executing the fs.readdirSync and fs.lstatSync.

Comment: Based on your earlier comment, 1) this.scanFiles() is called, 2) .then() callback is registered, 3) .catch() callback is registered, 4) console.log() ,  at which point does my fs.readdirSysnc and fs.lstatSync start running ? after point 3, and before point 4?

Comment: They are part of the `this.scanFiles()` call, and which in your code is a fully synchronous function, so both of them are called in step 1.

Comment: *"I thought the thread will create a new Promise(), and return it back to the caller"*. No, that's not how that works. `new Promise()` **immediately** calls its payload function. And it returns when the payload function returns. If the payload function blocks for 10 seconds (because it's synchronous, like in your case), then the `new Promise()` call will take 10 seconds. Promises do work with synchronous code, but they don't magically make that fact go away. You need to use asynchronous code all the way through in order to have any benefit.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak! I have finally understood the reason, and has make the tasks in the payload function asynchronous, and that solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my understanding of your current code, this is a fully asynchronous, promise-returning version of your `getContentInDirectory`. For the sake of testing, I found the TypeScript too noisy and removed it, add that back as you see fit.

```js
function getContentInDirectory(dir, filterContentFn, processContentFn, maxSubFolderDepth) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let result = [], pending = 0;
        function worker(currPath, depth) {
            pending++;
            fs.lstat(currPath, (err, stat) => {
                pending--;
                if (err) return reject(err);
                if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                    if (depth >= 0) {
                        pending++;
                        fs.readdir(currPath, (err, children) => {
                            pending--;
                            if (err) return reject(err);
                            children.forEach(name => worker(path.join(currPath, name), depth - 1));
                        });
                    }
                } else if (!filterContentFn || filterContentFn(currPath)) {
                    result.push(processContentFn ? processContentFn(currPath) : currPath);
                }
                if (!pending) resolve(result);
            });
        }
        worker(dir, maxSubFolderDepth >= 0 ? maxSubFolderDepth : Infinity);
    });
}
```

There are different ways to implement this, including using the [fs Promises API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api), which is available as of node version 10, but as of yet still marked "experimental". The above makes no assumptions and would work with any node version.

Now you can use that in `scanFiles` in the spirit of:

```js
function scanFiles(foldersPath) {
    let pendingPaths = foldersPath.map(currFolderPath => {
        return getContentInDirectory(currFolderPath, filterFunc, processFunc, depth);
    });
    return Promise.all(pendingPaths).then(results => {
        return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], results);  // flatten
    });
}
```

and finally in your event handler:

```js
onSubmit(){
    this.scanFiles(this.foldersPath).then(filesPath => {
        // after scan finish 
        console.log("this prints last");
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log("this prints first");
}
```

The thing to note here is that the function that is doing the actual work needs to be asynchronous from the start, if you want to be your consuming functions to be asynchronous as well. Switching from the "sync" versions of node's `fs` functions to the regular, async counterparts is the vital step.

Of course this change means that every consumer of `getContentInDirectory` in your program must be changed to async code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and patient to provide an implementation to make my function asynchronous. I will use your provide code as a reference to see how to incorporate into my application.

Comment: Once you have a function that returns a promise, you can start using the `async`/`await` semantics in any functions that call it, if you prefer that over the `.then()` semantics. Also, since you the worker function only using `fs.lstat()` and `fs.listdir()`, you can make promise-based variants of them specifically with node's `util.promisify()`. This could also result in nicer code than the current, callback-based ("node-style") approach.

Comment: Noted! Will try the async/await, once I have the promise in place. Thanks

Comment: Oops. I accidentally delete the query, which you are trying to answer. Nevertheless, I will take a closer look, could be bug in my program. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use several Then Chain Together:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 1
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) { // (***)

  alert(result); // 2
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 4
  return result * 2;

});
```

The idea is that the result is passed through the chain of .then handlers.

Here the flow is:

The initial promise resolves in 1 second (*),
Then the .then handler is called (**).
The value that it returns is passed to the next .then handler (***)
…and so on.

link [Promises chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

Or You can do something after all then executed, by write it in finally:

```
let isLoading = true;

fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
    var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
    if(contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
  })
  .then(function(json) { /* process your JSON further */ })
  .catch(function(error) { console.error(error); /* this line can also throw, e.g. when console = {} */ })
  .finally(function() { isLoading = false; });
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. But your response does not seem to address my query. My main concern was that I was expecting the "test1" to be printed out first, before the promise start doing its job.  But i was wrong, which is what lead me to ask this question.